# How can I get Response getBody() in Observer event?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

In Magento 1 I can do the following:

```
$response = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getResponse();
if(!$response) {
   return $this;
 }

$html = $response->getBody();
```

How can I do the same in Magento 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your module is under `Vendor\Module`

If you want to captures the HTML from the response, you can declare your event under `etc\<area>\events.xml` (where `<area>` is `adminhtml` or `frontend` ):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_front_send_response_before">
        <observer name="vendor_module" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Observer" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then under `Model\Observer.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {
        $response = $observer->getEvent()->getData('response');
        if (!$response) return;
        $body = $response->getBody();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's working fine thx right now i am not able to give you +50 because it's not completed 24 hours.