# Magento 2. Call .phtml (modal) from observer

Tags: magento2.2.2, modal-popup, custom-template

I have created a **custom .phtml** file that contains a **modal popup**.

I can successfully call this .phtml by adding it to default.xml in layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">   
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="root">'
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="redirectPopup" template="Magento_Store::switch/redirectPopup.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The code above working fine.

But I would like to call this template only if a certain condition is matched. That's why I want to call it from **observer** in my **custom module**.

I tried the following code in observer,

```
public function showRedirectPopup()
{
    $block = $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Store\Block\Switcher')->setTemplate('Magento_Store::switch/redirectPopup.phtml')->toHtml();
    return $block;
}
```

I have made sure the function *showRedirectPopup()* is executed. But it doesn't seems .phtml is being called.

Did I miss anything?

Can we at all call a .phtml from a observer or it has to be called from layout(.xml)?

Comment: I found it out. The reason the I could not get any HTML output, is because in my showRedirectPopup() function, I used "return", and thus I need to echo the function, but instead of echo, I used return again to call the showRedirectPopup() function.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if your script injects

> **\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory**

in the constructor.

After that in your execute function place this:

```
$layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();
$block = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Store\Block\Switcher')->setTemplate('Magento_Store::switch/redirectPopup.phtml')->toHtml();
return $block;
```

Now it should work

EDIT:

i see what i missed in my answer. Forgot to tell that you must set the response header and body, instead of returning the html directly. So it goes like this:

```
$block = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Store\Block\Switcher')->setTemplate('Magento_Store::switch/redirectPopup.phtml');
$response = $observer->getEvent()->getData('response');
$response
    ->setHeader('Content-Type','text/html')
    ->setBody($block->toHtml());
return;
```

Also make sure you pick an event that is fired later than **controller_action_predispatch** for example **controller_front_send_response_before**  because the response object doesn't exist yet. Using this object the right response type can be set

Comment: I didn't use LayoutFactory. But I have now added LayoutFactory as you suggested, still no popup.

Comment: I tried the new code, now I get this PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method getResponse().

Comment: Do I need to created an event for this?

Comment: because it's an observer the getresponse doesn't exist. In my code i use this in a controller which does have that function. Take a look here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108579/how-can-i-get-response-getbody-in-observer-event

Comment: I have edited my question. It seems if I use echo $block, then it will output the html from my custom .phtml. however the modal popup is not a popup now. it just being displayed on the page as plain html.

Comment: Can you tell me what event is calling your observer?

Comment: "store_load_after" and "controller_action_predispatch"

Comment: I see you have to have a different event because controller_action_predispatch doesn't have response as an object because it's loaded too early. You can change it to controller_front_send_response_before.